# How do I create crash log when the Android process crashes

Tags: android, logging, crash, acra

My Java code will invoke native code. When the native code crashes, I want to write the crash log to my own file. How can I achieve this? I have used ACRA, but it won't work for native code.
Thanks very much.

Comment: What is ACRA, do you have a link?

Comment: ACRA is an open source crash reporting tool for Android. http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 0):

A comment from an ACRA developer found [here](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRA3HowTo)

> Comment by project member kevin.gaudin, Dec 16, 2010
>
> Ok, I don't think we can do anything to catch native crashes if they don't result in a Java Exception.
>
> In a future release, I'm planning to add an option to (optionaly) upload a short logcat extract + DropBoxManager? system items. This should allow to get some of these traces, but only if an exception triggers the report... or if you detect an unexpected state and trigger a report yourself.

However, you might be able to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258444/741249)